# Solve SelectKBest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am having this error ..

I am trying to predict some data using maching learning. of a regression tree model. I have a low score, so I want to choose the most important features

For this I am using sklearn
SelectKBest, but I have the following error

How can I solve it?

Read Data

```
data = pd.read_csv("EquiposData.csv")

target = data.iloc[:,1:2]

datos  = data.iloc[:,2:]
```

SelectKbest

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression #Calcula la mejor selección

selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k=4)
selector.fit(datos,target)
scores = selector.scores_
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-341-7d9675b4a1f7> in <module>()
      4 
      5 selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k=4)
----> 6 selector.fit(datos,target)
      7 scores = selector.scores_

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py in fit(self, X, y)
    342         self : object
    343         """
--> 344         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc'],
    345                                    multi_output=True)
    346 

AttributeError: 'SelectKBest' object has no attribute '_validate_data'
```

Comment: The doc's `__init__` say: `Initialize self. See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.`. May be it is the problem, but I am baffling if be honest, it has to work

Comment: What version of sklearn?

Comment: The scikit-learn version is 0.22.2.post1.

Comment: `_validate_data` was added to `BaseEstimator` in v0.23; before that (in the 0.22.2.post1 snapshot, in particular), `SelectKBest` was using `check_X_y` at the top of its `fit` method instead.  It seems like your env is confused about which version of sklearn it's using, but I don't know how that would happen or how to remedy it.  Upgrade or remove+reinstall?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)